# Fragment with list not displayed as it should

Tags: android, android-studio-2.0

I created a fragment with a list on one column and I'd like it to be displayed this way : 
[image]

But when I run my app it's displayed this way :
[image]

When I created this fragment, android studio generated two xml files. This one is fragment_item.xml :
[image]
And this one is fragment_item_list :
[image]

Here is my fragment class :

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    private ItemFragment.OnListFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_list, container, false);
        // Set the adapter
            Context context = rootView.getContext();
            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView;
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, 2));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyItemRecyclerViewAdapter(DummyContent.ITEMS, mListener));
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

and here is my RecyclerView class :

```
public class MyItemRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyItemRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private final List<DummyItem> mValues;
private final OnListFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public MyItemRecyclerViewAdapter(List<DummyItem> items, OnListFragmentInteractionListener listener) {
    mValues = items;
    mListener = listener;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.fragment_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mItem = mValues.get(position);
    holder.mIdView.setText(mValues.get(position).id);
    holder.mContentView.setText(mValues.get(position).content);

    holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (null != mListener) {
                // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
                // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
                mListener.onListFragmentInteraction(holder.mItem);
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mValues.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public final View mView;
    public final TextView mIdView;
    public final TextView mContentView;
    public DummyItem mItem;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        mView = view;
        mIdView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id);
        mContentView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.content);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + " '" + mContentView.getText() + "'";
    }
}
```

}

Does anyone have an idea of how I could do to have the list like I would like ?

Comment: please add the class files in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In onCreateView you have specified number of columns as 2.
So change these line,

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, 2));
```

to

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, 1));
```